# Why are my user IDs not saving in conversation member array with MERN API and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mern

my api

```
app.post("/api/conversation",async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {sid,rid} =req.body;
        const newConversation = new Conversation({ members:[sid,rid]});
        await newConversation.save()
        res.status(200).send("created sucessfully")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)        
    }
})
```

my conversation model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  members:[ {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }],
});

const conversation = mongoose.model("conversation", conversationSchema);

module.exports = conversation;
```

as shown in the above code i have tested my api in postman and the api was sucessfull and it is appeared as created sucessfully but then i visited mongodb website to check my data base where the array is with two null values the id's i have passed are not reaching to my data base how to resolve this error

i am expecting that when i perform an api call it must contain an id and an array with two user id's

Answer (score 0):

Your Conversation Scheme are not correct definition, when you need save array you need set type like next example:

```
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  members:{
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: "User",
  },
});
```